# Insert same id from other database in magento api soap

Tags: php, mysql, magento, soap

I am using soap api to import a category data but it is creating a new id ,but i want to import same id which is already in other database.

like 
CategoryId=55, in other database

if i am using soap for importing database into magento and i didnot have any category in 55 it is not created giving error.
I want to same id of all category not want to change.

Required help.

Comment: The create method is purely for creating new categories and the record id is returned. If you need to map between the old and the new I normally simply create a CSV as the import script runs which records the old id and the new one and use the map accordingly for any further processing. You could always import manually into the database rather than use the API. The more complex option is to extend the API (Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api) to allow you to set an ID and override the create method so you can try calling $catgeory->setId($id) before save is invoked.

Comment: I am using this function $catgeory->setId($id),but it gives error **Category not exists**

Comment: thank you u are saying right. Ashley Swatton